# 404 resource not found api-platform

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

hello I created the little "foo" api with the api-platform and I am now trying to use my own entities but I keep getting the 404 error no resources found.

I am following this tutorial:
https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/

Here is my entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Job
 *
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var Location The location this job is about.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="jobs")
     */
    private $location;
```

If anyone can help my out why this doesnt work I would realy appreciate it :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with your controller/route, can you show its code?

Comment: Check out if you have the symfony's config.yml and parameters.yml correctly configured, and all the dependencies for api-platform in AppKernel

Comment: Check out if you have the symfony's config.yml and parameters.yml correctly configured, and all the dependencies for api-platform in AppKernel

Answer (score 4):

Most of the times after a modification on entity or creation of entity you have to run:

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear
```

in order the new changes to take effect.
I still haven't found a way to disable cache for dev mode.

Comment: Life saver for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I had run my server with `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`
and then I used `symfony server:start`, and with this worked as supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's the missing ".htaccess" file in the public folder. It's missing every time when installing a new project, when I use the composer setup.

After copying the ".htaccess" to the new project, it works fine.